# How to stop useEffect from inifite loop when first setting state and then using state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

There are plenty of questions about this topic already but none I could see that both set the state then use that same state.

I am setting state on the first run and then passing the state back in via the array. In theory, this should run only 2 times, once when `data1` and `data2` are blank and then again when they change to updated.

Passing in the state this way makes it run forever currently. How do I stop this? The data is not updating so why is it running over and over? Or do this another way?

I don't want `combineData` running each time a change is made as it is not necessary. I want this to take place on load only (like I am trying to do here).

```
const [data1, setData1] = useState('')
const [data2, setData2] = useState('')
const [data, setData] = useState('')


useEffect(() => {
   ///SET STATE
    data1
      .getData1(getData1Func)
      .then((res) => setData1(res))
    data2
      .getData2(getData2Func)
      .then((res) => setData2(res))
    ///USE STATE
    combineData(data1, data2)
  }, [data1, data2]) // pass in an array as a second argument

const combineData = (...args) => {
    let data = [...args].flat()
    setData(data)
  }
```

Comment: wait until all promises are complete and remove the data1 and data2 from the dependency array. e.g. `Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(results => { /*combine here*/})`, `results` will be an array in the format `[promise1Result, promise2Result]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the state, yet you are using those state as dependency, so it becomes a infinite loop.

If you only want to use it once then remove the dependencies.

```
useEffect(() => {

   // your codes.

},[])
```

If not, then there's not necessary to use state, instead, use local variables.

```
useEffect(() => {
   ///SET STATE
    const initiate = async () => {

    const local1 = await getData1()
    const local2 = await getData2()

    combineData(local1, local2)
   }

   initiate();
  }, []) // pass in an array as a second argument

const combineData = (...args) => {
    let data = [...args].flat()
    setData(data)
  }
```

Comment: This is a good and simple solution (the second part) and it solved my problem.